# GET http://localhost:8000/posts 404 (Not Found) - ERROR While connecting trying to fetch Posts saved in Mongodb using Angular

Tags: angular, mongodb

I am trying to fetch Posts saved in Mongodb using Angular.

> GET http://localhost:8000/posts 404 (Not Found)
>
> ERROR: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404,
> statusText: 'Not Found', url: 'http://localhost:8000/posts', ok:
> false, …}

Please find my code below:

API for fetching Posts:

```
 getAllPosts(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/posts');

   }

Actual Method for fetching Posts:

displayPosts(){
    this.getAllPosts()
    .subscribe((item)=>{
      this.responseData = item;
    })
  }
```

Backend Route:

```
router.post('/posts', getAllPosts);
```

Method for backend fetching Posts:

```
const getAllPosts = async(request,response)=>{
    try{
        const posts = await post.find({});
        return response.status(200).json(posts);
    }
    catch(err){
        return  response.status(400).json(err);
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```js
router.post('/posts', getAllPosts);
```

You can get your posts only with POST method.

Either use

```js
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/posts');
```

on the clientside. Or change backend method to

```
router.get('/posts', getAllPosts);
```